# I have file in folder but how to get to know file extension

Tags: php

In my images folder have file

```
1_cover.???
2_cover.???
3_cover.???
4_cover.???
5_cover.???
```

I wanna get file extension 4_cover.???
How to write PHP code

==========

## UPDATE

Thanks for all help me,
I can use this code

```
$images = glob("./images/4_cover.*");
print_r($images);
```

Comment: why are you dong this? why are you not storing the origianl extension?

Comment: on database use first number file = primary key of table + "_cover"
not record file name to table

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for ?

```
$info = new SplFileInfo('photo.jpg');
$path = $info->getExtension();
var_dump($path);
```

[PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/splfileinfo.getextension.php)

Comment: on Database not have image name
first number of filename's id + "_cover"
but i don't know extension jpg, png, gif

Comment: Well. We can't guess the extension of your file, in my opinion. You have to keep the data somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look in a directory for files, this might not be the best suited way to do your method but since you don't know what the file-type is, you can do something like this: (all code should be in order from top-bottom)

**The directory housing all of your files**

```
$directory = "public/images/headers/*";
```

**The files gathered from the `glob` function, use `print_r($files)` to see all of the files gathered for debugging if there's an error going on**

```
$files = glob( $directory );
```

**The file you said you were looking for, if this is from a database you'll replace this data with data from the database**

```
$filename_to_lookfor = '4_cover.';
```

**If statements to check the file types and see if they're existant**

```
$file_types_to_check_for = ['gif', 'jpg', 'png'];

foreach ($file_types_to_check_for as $filetype)
  if (in_array( $filename_to_lookfor.$filetype, $files)
  echo "This is a {$filetype} file!";
```

**After reading more into glob** - I'm not too experienced with it.

You can simply write this line:

```
if (count($files = glob( 'public/images/4_cover.*' )) != 0) $file = $files[0]; else echo 'No file with extension!';
```

**or**

```
$file = (count($files = glob('public/images/4_cover.*') != 0)) ? $files[0] : 'NO_FILE' ;
```

I apologize for the quite bad quality code, but that's what OP wants and that's the easiest way I could think to do that for him.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pathinfo function](http://php.net/manual/es/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$file = "file.php";
$path_parts = pathinfo($file);
$path_parts['extension']; // return => 'php'
```